# Можно ли создать файл без сохранения на устройство?

Tags: android

Есть вот такой код. Можно ли создать файл без сохранения на устройство?

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
    fun toFile(body: ResponseBody): File? {
        try {
            val filePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).path
            val futureStudioIconFile = File(filePath + File.separator + "${body.hashCode()}.png")
            var inputStream: InputStream? = null
            var outputStream: OutputStream? = null
            try {
                val fileReader = ByteArray(4096)
                var fileSizeDownloaded: Long = 0
                inputStream = body.byteStream()
                outputStream = FileOutputStream(futureStudioIconFile)
                while (true) {
                    val read: Int = inputStream.read(fileReader)
                    if (read == -1) {
                        break
                    }
                    outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read)
                    fileSizeDownloaded += read.toLong()
                }
                outputStream.flush()
                return futureStudioIconFile
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                return null
            } finally {
                inputStream?.close()
                outputStream?.close()
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            return null
        }
    }
```

Comment: а что представляет собой файл, который не сохранен на устройство?

Comment: Поясните смысл вопроса. Если речь об использовании полученных данных без сохранения в файл, то конечно можно. Создать массив и записать в него данные либо конвертировать поток в целевой объект (например `Bitmap` для картинки) - оба варианта будут в оперативной памяти и исчезнут как только перестанут использоваться. Но надо иметь в виду, что для больших файлов и/или большого их количества памяти может не хватить

Comment: Да именно это мне и нужно. Bitmap не подходит т.к мне нужно прокидывать картинку дальше до ViewModel, но в Clean нет доступа к Bitmap в Repository и UseCase слое. Можете подробнее рассказать про "Создать массив и записать в него данные"

Comment: Не совсем понимаю почему нельзя Bitmap, если можно массив - по сути это тоже массив (пикселей) в классе-обёртке. Но если так надо, то самое простое - заменить в вашем коде `FileOutputStream` на `ByteArrayOutputStream`, после вычитывания данных можно получить массив: `outputStream.toByteArray()`

Comment: спасибо. решение подошло